# Replace Fragment inside a ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

It's `ViewPager, ViewPagerAdapter,TabLayout`  and  `Fagment1, Fragment2, Fragment3`. `ViewPager` show 2 fragments.

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter mVPAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_1(), "");
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_2(), "");
viewPager.setAdapter(mVPAdapter); 
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Can I replace `Fragment1` on `Fragment3` with `ViewPagerAdapter`?

Comment: change this
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_2(), "");
to
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_3(), "");

Comment: I need to show fragment2, and then show fragment3; Can I do this with ViewPagerAdapter?

Comment: Here this tutorial may help for your problem http://www.pineappslab.com/post/fragments-viewpager/.

Comment: see this link https://dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Fragment fragment_name = new Fragment_3();
 attachFragment(childFragment, Constant.TAG_FRAGMENT3, true);
```

In attachfragment you will replace the fragment1 from fragment3. you can use the boolean varible to add that fragment into backstack

```
private void attachFragment(Fragment mFragment, String mID,
                                boolean doAddToStack) {

        mTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.container) != null) {

            mTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mFragment, mID);
            if (doAddToStack) {
                mTransaction.addToBackStack(mID);
            }
        } else {
            mTransaction.add(R.id.container, mFragment, mID);

        }
        mTransaction.commit();

    }
```